# show/hide password text using angular2

Tags: angular

i want to show/hide the password text based on the user click. But i am getting the following error saying:

[image]

```
export class App {
    password = "secret";
    show = false;

    @ContentChild(ShowHideInput) input: ShowHideInput;

    constructor(){}

    toggleShow()
    {
        this.show = !this.show;
        console.log(this.input); //undefined
        if (this.show){
            this.input.changeType("text");
        }
        else {
            this.input.changeType("password");
        }
    }
}
```

The following plunker link which i have created.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/2GK79PuPtRQNmoUbF6xC?p=preview
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `ViewChild()` instead of `ContentChild()`

```
@ViewChild(ShowHideInput) input: ShowHideInput;
```

[check your plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/RFzSrtUvWfWrFORUVDy5?p=preview)

`ContentChild()` is for matching inside the transcluded content. e.g. contents inside `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Comment: You are welcome @vishnu. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 60):

This is a *better answer*. Check below:

**input**

```
<input [type]="show ? 'text' : 'password'" />
```

**click action**

```
<button (click)="password()">{{show ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}</button>
```

**component**

```
// variable - default false
show: boolean = false;

constructor() {
}

// click event function toggle
password() {
    this.show = !this.show;
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! I looked for a clean answer exactly like yours. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 13):

You could also do all of this in the template in a quick and dirty way..

```
<input #x type="password">
<button (click)="x.type=x.type=='password'?'text':'password'"></button>
```

Comment: the better answer for me 

Comment: So simple to implement. Love it!!

Answer (score 3):

```
<input [type]="show_button ? 'text' : 'password'">
<i [class]="show_eye ? 'fa fa-eye' : 'fa fa-eye-slash'" (click)="showPassword()"> // Modify style as you need

 // variable
  show_button: Boolean = false;
  show_eye: Boolean = false;

//Function
showPassword() {
    this.show_button = !this.show_button;
    this.show_eye = !this.show_eye;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

in you html :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" #password-field>
    <span (click)="password-field.type=password-field.type=='password'?'text':'password'" 
    class="fa fa-fw field-icon toggle-password"
        [ngClass]="(password-field.type=='password')?' fa-eye':' fa-eye-slash'"></span>
</div>
```

in your css or sass

```
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  left: -15px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that in the approach from the question functionality is implemented directly in the component where the `<input>` is and just for the record I want to share a more elegant approach - ***creating a component for the purpose***

Check the demo plunkr [**HERE**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2typZamWDFY7BgVkLHL6?p=preview), can be useful for others.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
//In HTML
<div>
<input [type] = "passType" placeholder="password">
</div>

<input type = "checkbox" (click)="changePasswordType()">Show Password

//In TS file
passType: string = 'password';

changePasswordType(){
if(this.passType== 'password'){
this.passType= 'text'
}else{
this.passType== 'password'
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation to your solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

In your App class.

```
   _show = false
   _pwdType = 'pwd'

   toggleShow() {

      this._show = !this._show
      this._pwdType = this._show ? 'text' : 'password'

   }//toggleShow
```

In your html

```
 <input [type]="_pwdType" class="form-control" ...etc">
```

Having said that I like @codtex's answer better